# assigning values in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, variable-assignment

I have a numpy array of zeros. For concreteness, suppose it's 2x3x4:

```
x = np.zeros((2,3,4))
```

and suppose I have a 2x3 array of random integers from 0 to 3 (the index of the 3rd dimension of x).

```
>>> y = sp.stats.distributions.randint.rvs(0, 4, size=(2,3))
>>> y
[[2 1 0]
 [3 2 0]]
```

How do I do the following assignments efficiently (edit: something that doesn't use for loops and works for x with any number of dimensions and any number of elements in each dimension)?

```
>>> x[0,0,y[0,0]]=1
>>> x[0,1,y[0,1]]=1
>>> x[0,2,y[0,2]]=1
>>> x[1,0,y[1,0]]=1
>>> x[1,1,y[1,1]]=1
>>> x[1,2,y[1,2]]=1
>>> x
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, I can only think of the “simple” version, which involves flattening along the first two dimensions. This code should work:

```
shape_last = x.shape[-1]
x.reshape((-1, shape_last))[np.arange(y.size), y.flatten()] = 1
```

This yields (with my randomly-generated `y`):

```
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

The key is, if you do an indexing using multiple numpy arrays ([advanced indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing)), numpy will use pairs of indices to index into the array.

Of course, make sure `x` and `y` are both either C-order or F-order — otherwise, the calls to `reshape` and `flatten` might give different orders.

Comment: This definitely works faster than the for loops I was using, and it seems to scale really well with the number of dimensions and number of elements in each dimension. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use [numpy.meshgrid](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html)() to make arrays of indexes that you can use to index into both your original array and the array of values for the third dimension.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.stats.distributions

a = np.zeros((2,3,4))
z = sp.stats.distributions.randint.rvs(0, 4, size=(2,3))

xx, yy = np.meshgrid( np.arange(2), np.arange(3) )
a[ xx, yy, z[xx, yy] ] = 1
print a
```

I've renamed your array from x to a, and the array of indexes from y to z, for clarity.

**EDIT:** 4D example:

```
a = np.zeros((2,3,4,5))
z = sp.stats.distributions.randint.rvs(0, 4, size=(2,3))
w = sp.stats.distributions.randint.rvs(0, 5, size=(2,3))

xx, yy = np.meshgrid( np.arange(2), np.arange(3) )
a[ xx, yy, z[xx, yy], w[xx, yy] ] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you know how to generalize this to a with any number of dimensions?

Comment: @user1857751: yes, of course, it generalizes in a straightforward way.  meshgrid to create vectors of indexes in all the dimensions that you do *not* want to lookup, and then use those to index the original array and the indexes you do want to look up.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = np.zeros((2,3,4))
y=np.array([[2, 1, 0],[3, 2, 0]]) # or y=sp.stats...
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(3):
        x[i,j,y[i,j]]=1
```

will produce the desired result, IIRC.  If the array dimensions never change, consider replacing the two for loops and their burden by

```
for j in range(3):
    x[0,j,y[0,j]] = x[1,j,y[1,j]] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the problem is that I need to do this efficiently for large arrays. In other words, I want to avoid for loops.

Comment: I need code that will handle any dimensions for x, i.e. any number of dimensions or any number of elements in each dimension.

Comment: I'm not highly familiar with numpy so I don't know if it has a relevant builtin function to do the job.  Of course there are [related routines](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.sort.html) argwhere, nonzero, where, and extract that can do the opposite eg can find the locations of non-zeros in an array